# What are facebook's og:type's allowed values?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have found links to this page, but it does not supply the information I need:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#types

What are the possible types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `type` for an `og:type` property can be anything you want it to be, as long as you have an [Open Graph Story](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/#stories) set up in your application. When you are setting up your story, you will be asked to provide an `action`, such as "cook", "eat", "walk", etc, and an object, such as "food", "dessert", or "route". That object is incorporated into the "type" that you provide in your open graph tags.

For example, if my app, DessertTaster, had an open graph story:

```
{user} tasted this dessert
```

The verb (action) is "taste", and the object is "dessert", and the corresponding `og:type` tag is:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="desserttaster:dessert" />
```

If you developed an app that used one of the default stories (and this is encouraged by facebook), then you might have an og story pair that had an action `news.reads` with object `article`.

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

In that case, no app namespace is required.

Answer (score 2):

There is a link in the [Facebook Developers Sharing Guide for Webmasters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters) to the [List of Types](https://ogp.me/?fbclid=IwAR0Dr3Rb3tw1W5wjFtuRMZfwewM2vlrSnNp-_ZKlvCzo5nKuX2TuTqt0kU8#types), which are:

```
music.song
music.album
music.playlist
music.radio_station
video.movie
video.episode
video.tv_show
video.other
article
book
profile
website
```